# How can I slow down rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to copy the contents of a failing USB thumb drive.  If I read the data too fast, the drive's controller chip overheats and the drive vanishes from the system.  When that happens, I need to unplug the drive, wait a minute or so for it to cool, plug it back in, and re-start the copy.

I've got an old backup of the contents of the drive, so the obvious way to get the rest of the data is to use `rsync` to bring the backup up to date, but this runs into the whole "read too fast, the drive vanishes, and I need to start over" issue.  Is there a way to tell `rsync` to only read X megabytes of data per minute?  Alternatively, is it possible to tell it to suspend operations when the drive vanishes, and resume when it gets plugged back in?

Comment: Have you thought about cooling the drive?

Comment: How full is the drive? If the drive is more than 50% full it is likely better to just mirror the failing drive first and then only start to deal with more complicated stuff on the mirror.

Comment: @AEonAX: While a cool (sic!) out-of-the-box idea, I wouldn't recommend this: you're putting additional thermal stress on the device, and it might fail completely.

Comment: This feels like the geek's equivalent of a first world problem. I have it too, my USB dock gets overloaded by the huge backup job.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Unlike DopeGhoti's experience, the `--bwlimit` flag does limit data transfer, with my rsync (v3.1.2).

test:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=10 of=data
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0871822 s, 120 MB/s

$ du -h data
10M     data

$ time rsync -q data fast
0.065 seconds

$ time rsync -q --bwlimit=1M data slow
10.004 seconds
```

(note: my `time` output looks different to most `time` invocations (`zsh` feature), those times weren't edited by me)

Else, perhaps something along the lines of a double `-exec` in `find`. I *believe* that `rsync -R` should create & copy the parent folders, but if it doesn't, then `cp --parents` should.

```
$ find /failing/usb -exec rsync -R {} /somewhere/safe/ \; -exec sleep 1 \;
```

**Note**: also check out [ddrescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue), it might be right what you're looking for :)

Comment: Yup. DG may have gotten confused by the word "bandwidth" - but that applies to any data-carrying channel, not only network. Man page specifically says: `--bwlimit=KBPS          limit I/O bandwidth; KBytes per second`, no mention of network. Casually browsing the code, this limits the *read* speed, regardless of destination. Plus, anecdote: I've been using this option for *years* now to limit local-to-local write speed. https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: Okay, on second look, it actually counts the number of bytes written and sleeps for a calculated time. `io.c`, lines 832-3: `if (bwlimit_writemax) sleep_for_bwlimit(n);` In any case, this would probably work as intended, reading in short bursts and sleeping in-between. I would recommend starting out with a low value and carefully increasing, or just let the slow transfer run overnight.

Answer (score 27):

A bit of a MacGyver solution but I have had good success with it in the past:
Put an old USB 1 hub between the stick and the computer. No way in hell it is going to copy fast that way :-)

Other possibility: If you've got another stick available put it on another USB port connected to the same root-hub (so it shares bandwidth with your problem stick).
Now start a big write operation to the extra stick so both sticks are competing for bandwidth. For further control you can use **ionice** to lower the priority on the problem stick even further.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a way to make the ports work as USB 1.1 via a software solution, possibly by giving options to the USB kernel module.

Comment: @AndréBorie: There is - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1342593#p1342593 , but since there are effective throttles in SW, this is a bit of a brute-force solution.

Comment: @Piskvor it negotiates a lower transfer rate with the device, just like using an USB 1 hub would do. I don't see anything "brute force" about it.

Comment: Okay, bad choice of word, I admit. But IMHO reconfiguring devices would require special privileges (root or at least %adm), whereas controlling per-process read speed would be simpler. (Plus, there are devices that fail to work outside USB 2.0 at all - in violation of the spec)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `rsync --bwlimit=RATE` to throttle the file transfer speed which, based on comments below, actually specifically seems to work by throttling the read speed of the data, which is precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: `ionice` ?  https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice

Comment: ionice just gives priority, if two things are reading then, by default they get 50/50. ionice can adjust that,  but if there is only one thing reading, then it will get 100% .

Comment: @coteyr You're right and that is why you need to combine it with a 2nd bandwidth eating process on the same USB root-hub. See my answer.

Comment: Fortunately, your answer is incorrect: `--bwlimit` sets I/O limit, not necessarily a *network* limit. Tested many times in various scenarios: this option makes rsync limit itself on *read*, regardless of the destination. (Found this out in a similar scenario, where fast writes to a slow local device made them fail)

Comment: @piskvor - thanks for that! That's what I love about this place; I keep learning new things (:

Answer (score 13):

More solutions, in addition to the `rsync --bwlimit=100`, for 100KiB/s.

1. Use `ddrescue` with the `--max-read-rate` option for a full disk copy. This will also allow you to restart a full disk copy where it left off after an error.

   ```
   ddrescue --max-read-rate=100K /failing/usb output.img output.logfile
   ```

`ddrescue` also has lots of other options relevant to data recovery, [see the manual here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html).

2. Use `pv` ("pipe viewer") with the `--rate-limit` option, or the `throttle` tool to rate limit pipes. `pv` can also show progress. You can make this work for any tool that uses a pipe or can use a pipe:

   ```
   tar -cf - /failing/usb | throttle -K 100 | tar -C /your/outputfolder/ -xvf -
   ```

   or

   ```
   tar -cf - /failing/usb | pv --rate-limit 100k | tar -C /your/outputfolder/  -xvf -
   ```

   Take a look at the [pv manpage](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml) for more settings and examples. For `throttle`, you might want to also try out `-w` option, which determines how the speed is calculated, see the [throttle manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/throttle).

Comment: Now that's a useful tool, didn't know that, thanks! `pv` manpage has even more examples of various usages.

Comment: I've reached for `pv` over and over again ever since discovering back in my tape jocking days.  Back when tar wrote to tape drives.  :)